# How do you say "I'm having dinner/lunch/breakfast" in Latin?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, phrase-request, word-choice

I know that *cena* means dinner, *prandium* means lunch, and *ientaculum* means breakfast. But how do you say "I'm having dinner" (or lunch, or breakfast)? I can think of a few ideas, such as:

- Habeo cenam. Habeo prandium. Habeo ientaculum.
- Edo cenam. Edo prandium. Edo ientaculum.

But I really have no clue what is correct and idiomatic.

Lastly, how would you say "I'm having a snack", or "I'm eating dessert"? I recently read that *merenda* is the word for a snack, and *secunda mensa* is the word for dessert. But I wouldn't know what verb or expression to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some meals have their own verbs: *cenare*, *prandere*, and others if I forget something.
If you are having dinner or lunch, say *ceno* or *prandeo*.

All things edible do not have their own verbs — nor do I think one should derive a new verb for every food item.
The crucial question is to find the best verb for these purposes.
I propose *sumere*.
The verb *consumere* is also possible, but it may be too intense, unless you "eat up" or "devour" your meal.
These verbs work for both foods and drinks.

The verb *edere* is also good.
I would probably use *edere* or *sumere*, depending on context.

I think *habere* is incorrect here.
If you say *cenam habeo*, I think you are in possession of a dinner.
Perhaps you brought takeaway with you but it's still in the fridge?
The English phrase "to have a meal" is misleading here, and I don't think it works in Latin.

Comment: *Sumere* is indeed correct, as we see in Martial 13.31.1: *Si sine carne voles **ientacula sumere** frugi,/Haec tibi Vestino de grege massa venit.*